# Why core dumped when using darknet

Tags: ubuntu, yolo, darknet

I have Ubuntu-20 and 4046mb GPU memory on Nvidia GTX 960M. Also i installed Cuda and Cudnn toolkits and make the darknet Makefile with GPU configurations. but when i want to train or test my model, i give following error:

```
 CUDA-version: 11010 (11050), cuDNN: 8.0.5, GPU count: 1  
 OpenCV version: 4.2.0
 0 : compute_capability = 500, cudnn_half = 0, GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960M 
net.optimized_memory = 0 
mini_batch = 1, batch = 1, time_steps = 1, train = 0 
   layer   filters  size/strd(dil)      input                output
   0 Create CUDA-stream - 0 
Bus error (core dumped)
```

also first part of my `yolov3.cfg` is:

```
batch=1
subdivisions=1
width=416
height=416
channels=3
momentum=0.9
decay=0.0005
angle=0
saturation = 1.5
exposure = 1.5
hue=.1

learning_rate=0.001
burn_in=1000
max_batches = 6000
policy=steps
steps=4800, 5400
scales=.1,.1
```

Comment: Start the program under gdb and run, the logs should indicate where the issue is.

Comment: thnx... but, how can i do that? =|